# Apache Drill SYSTEM ERROR: UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported format

Tags: apache-drill

I am using Drill's CTAS function to create a json file of my output. I am getting the following error.

> org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: SYSTEM ERROR: UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported format 'null' in workspace 'hivetest1.hive' [Error Id: 3e74fde2-b2e5-4799-a4f9-0236d003ab31 on centos6.qubida.io:31010]

the same error occurs if i am using json in defaultInputFormat also.
 Unsupported format 'json' in workspace. I tried to remove the defaultInputFormat itself. But not able to create the workspace.

My storage is

```
{
  "type": "file",
  "enabled": true,
  "connection": "file:///",
  "config": null,
  "workspaces": {
    "hive": {
      "location": "/tmp/",
      "writable": true,
      "defaultInputFormat": null
    }
  },
  "formats": {
    "json": {
      "type": "json",
      "extensions": [
        "json"
      ]
    }
  }
```

I have even tried with different defaultInputFormat. I have set store.format also to JSON. I have changed store.mongo.all_text_mode also to true.store.json.all_text_mode is also true. But still, I am getting the same error. What needs to be changed. I am using drill 1.6. My CTAS query is

`` create table hivetest1.hive.`output_json` as select distinct buildingid, country, temprange from hive.`sensorfiles`.`hvac_building` where extremetemp = '1' ``

I am able to view the output for the search query alone. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate your issue. But it's working.

All I did is:

- Started drill 1.6 in embedded mode
- Added plugin mentioned by you in the question
- `` alter session set `store.format`='json'; ``
- `` create table hivetest1.hive.`output.json` as  SELECT * FROM cp.`employee.json` LIMIT 20; ``

Everything is working fine.

Comment: is there any requirement that the table from which i am selecting needs to be json?

Comment: getting same error even for a json table. any issues on how drill is configured?

Comment: i am able to save as 0_0_0.parquet file, even if  i am setting the output as a json file. this happens when i remove json format from the formats. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Krishna No in select query you can use any table or file .

Comment: @Krishna be default `store.format` is `parquet` go to :  http://localhost:8047/options and check

Comment: needed to change the store.format to json. Now working. But should it be working even if we set using alter session?